# How can I draw this Automata with Tikz?

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphs, automata

I want something like the figure:

[image]

But what I got is:

[image]

this is my code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
        % position the nodes a..d
        \node (a) [] {$\textrm{I}$};
        \node (b) [right of=a] {};
        \node (c) [right of=b] {};
        \node (d) [right of=c] {};
        \node (e) [right of=d] {};
        \node (f) [right of=e] {};
        \node (g) [right of=f] {};
        \node (h) [right of=g] {};
        \node (i) [right of=h] {};
        \node (j) [right of=i] {};
        \node (k) [right of=j] {};
        \node (l) [right of=k] {};
        
        % draw the bullets/circles at the above defined positions
        \filldraw (b) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (c) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (d) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (e) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (f) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw (f) circle (5pt);
        
        
        \filldraw (g) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (h) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (i) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (j) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (k) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (l) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw (l) circle (5pt);

        
        % draw arrows/connections, use 'shorten' to finetune space
        \path[draw, ->, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=-2pt] (a) -- (b) ; 
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (b) -- (c) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (c) -- (d) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$1$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (d) -- (e) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (e) -- (f) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$0$};
        
        
        
        
        
        \path[->, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=1pt, bend left] 
        (b) edge node [above=0., pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$} (g) ;
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (g) -- (h) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$0$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (h) -- (i) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (i) -- (j) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$0$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (j) -- (k) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$};
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (k) -- (l) 
        node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$1$};                 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Does anyone know how to make the graph look like the first figure (Photograph)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `below right`, `above right` etc. in order to position nodes in those directions, relative to the current node. It requires the `positioning` library to access the extra options.

Also, you could add a few custom styles to avoid repetition.

The example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1.5cm,
        every node/.style={draw, fill, circle, inner sep=1.5pt},
        endnode/.style={fill=none, inner sep=5pt},
        every edge/.style={draw, ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
        itslabel/.style={draw=none, fill=none, above=0pt, pos=0.5},
    ]
        % position the nodes a..d
        \node (a) [draw=none,fill=none, font=\large] {I};
        \node (b) [right=of a] {};
        \node (c) [above right=of b] {};
        \node (d) [right=of c] {};
        \node (e) [right=of d] {};
        \node (f) [right=of e] {};
        \node (fend) [endnode] at (f) {};
        \node (g) [below right=of b] {};
        \node (h) [right=of g] {};
        \node (i) [right=of h] {};
        \node (j) [right=of i] {};
        \node (k) [right=of j] {};
        \node (l) [right=of k] {};
        \node (lend) [endnode] at (l) {};

        \path (a.center) edge (b) 
              (b) edge node [itslabel, pos=0.38, above=5pt] {\(\varepsilon\)} (c)
              (c) edge node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (d)
              (d) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (e)
              (e) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {0} (f)
              (b) edge node [itslabel, pos=0.32, below=5pt] {\(\varepsilon\)} (g)
              (g) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (h)
              (h) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (i)
              (i) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (j)
              (j) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (k)
              (k) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (l);              
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't very clear in the question. The size of the vertices and edges that I got in the output were meeting my needs. I want only the arrangement of the vertices to change in relation to the output I got. Could you please change the code you sent so that the graph goes back to its default size?

Comment: @B612 I think this should do. If you want to adjust the size of black nodes, change the value of `inner sep` in the line: `every node/.style={draw, fill, circle, inner sep=1.5pt}`. Circles with dotes, which I called `endnode`s are defined in the following line.